# Time series anomaly detection plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a pandas dataframe of size (1280,2).  The head of the data looks as follows:
[image]

I'm using a clustering based anomaly detection method using k-means.  It creates 'k' similar clusters of data points.  Data points that fall outside of these groups are marked as anomalies.

```
def getDistanceByPoint(data, model):
distance = pd.Series()
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    Xa = np.array(data.loc[i])
    Xb = model.cluster_centers_[model.labels_[i]-1]
    distance.set_value(i, np.linalg.norm(Xa-Xb))
return distance
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=9).fit(data) 
outliers_fraction = 0.01
distance = getDistanceByPoint(data, kmeans)
number_of_outliers = int(outliers_fraction*len(distance))
threshold = distance.nlargest(number_of_outliers).min()
(0:normal, 1:anomaly) 
df['anomaly1'] = (distance >= threshold).astype(int)
```

I want to plot data frame with the x-axis as time elapsed and the y-axis as value.  I would like to plot the normal data values in blue and the anomaly values in red.  How could I plot this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. Remember to change `time` and `value` to your column name accordingly.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a = df.loc[df['anomaly'] == 1, ['time', 'value']]
ax.plot(df['time'], df['value'], color='blue')
ax.scatter(a['time'], a['value'], color='red')
plt.show()
```

Check [this notebook](https://github.com/Vicam/Unsupervised_Anomaly_Detection/blob/master/Anomaly%20detection%2C%20different%20methods%20on%20a%20simple%20example.ipynb) out for more information.